# Mongoose: update 1 key and delete another key in the same object

Tags: mongoose

Is it possible to update the `password` and delete the `resetPasswordCode` at the same time?

```
  static confirmPassword = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { newPassword, resetPasswordCode } = req.body;
    const account = await userModel.findOne({resetPasswordCode}).exec();
    if (!account) res.status(400).send({ message: 'You have not requested a reset' });
    const hours = Math.floor((Date.now() - Date.parse(account.resetSentAt)) / 3600000);
    if (hours >= 12) res.status(400).send({ message: 'Reset code is invalid' });
    else {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 10);
      const updated = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {resetPasswordCode},
        {$set: {password: hashedPassword}},
        {$unset: {resetPasswordCode}}
    }).exec();
      if (updated) res.status(200).send({ message: 'Password Reset' });
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like you just need to merge `{$set: {password: hashedPassword}}` and `{$unset: {resetPasswordCode}}` into one object. Something like:

```
await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {resetPasswordCode},
    {
      $set: {password: hashedPassword},
      $unset: {resetPasswordCode: ""}
    }
})...
```